# Loggin Text File Changes After Saving

Tags: plugins, version-control, notepad++

Does anyone know about a plugin for notepad++ or any tool that is capable of logging the changes of a text file? Simply like version control systems (SVN or GIT) but the difference is that I would like to log the changes on save without the need to commit after each change.

Thanks,
TeFa

Comment: If it is possible, maybe you could write a plugin which does VCS commit on save. But why would you do this? It sounds like commit history would be quite ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of something like that in Notepad++. But maybe `Autosave2` plugin will suit you.

Go to `Plugins` > `Plugin Manager` > `Autosave2` and install it. Follows its own description:

> Allows you to automatically save your Notepad++ text with a timestamp.
>
> This plugin does create new files (ie. copies) of the currently opened files.
>   The original files will not be saved automatically. (So basically, it is more a Autocopy rather than a Autosave)
>
> Using a timer schedule and timestamps in the newly created filenames you will have a history of changed files like this:

```
ToDo.txt.2013-04-19 10.13.09
ToDo.txt.2013-04-19 10.14.09
ToDo.txt.2013-04-19 10.15.09
```